# Where mysql keep index file on cluster environment?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

It's easy to understand about creating index on any column on a simple MySQL service.
All index kept in one node.

But if it's clustered MySQL which store data of one table on multiple node.
Where is the index kept?

Thanks.